# How do I pulling in historical daily trade volume data in Google Sheets with Google Finance?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-finance

If I try `=GOOGLEFINANCE(A1,"volume",A2)` where `A1` is the stock code and `A2` is the date I'm querying, it comes back printing 'date' and 'volume' on one line as headers and then the data on the line below. Is there a way to have this formula printing on each line without the headers?

e.g. `GOOG`

```
A1  13/06/20  B1 daily volume  
A2  12/06/20  B2 daily volume
A3  11/06/20  B3 daily volume
```

I'm just trying to build the formula that can give the data for B1,B2,B3 etc and drag it down so the data is on each line querying the respective date in column A.

What formula do I need to use?

Answer (score 1):

It's rather easy to get a list of data: just add the number of days as a parameter, e.g.

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE(A1,"volume",A2,30)
```

Specifying start and end date is also possible, see the [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en).

[image]

If you want it for specific (non-consecutive) dates, I'd suggest to use `VLOOKUP` or some other query method. An example:

The Finance formula is now `=GOOGLEFINANCE(A1,"volume",MIN(A2:A100),MAX(A2:A100))` and the second column is `=VLOOKUP(A2+TIME(16,0,0),D:E,2,FALSE)`; adding 16 hours is one possible way to make sure it matches the timestamp in the 'Date' column.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but how do I get it to actually query the specific dates in column A? 

I've tried VLookup but cant get the formula right. 

=GOOGLEFINANCE(A1,"volume",A2,30)prints out the results as you have it above but how do I amend it so it queries the specific date? What I want to be able to do is put the formula in B2 and drag it down to query the volume of a specific stock against a specific date. 

  I have 10/06/2020, 09/06/2020, 08/06/2020, 05/06/2020, 04/06/2020 in column A and I want to have the specific volume in column B and drag down the formula.

Thanks a lot! I appreciate it.

Comment: @Charlie see the updated answer. VLOOKUP is a bit tricky here because of the timestamp returned by Google Finance, but it's doable.